# Why can't get this Rspec test passed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Im following Michael Hartl's ROR tutorials . I got stuck at testing the authentication_pages. I have checked with the book for a couple times. it seems nothing wrong there, i have no idea for the issue now. Let me include the details. Your help will be greatly appreciated!

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/

1) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: click_button "Sign in"
     ActionView::MissingTemplate:
       Missing template sessions/create, application/create with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :jbuilder, :coffee]}. Searched in:
         * "/Users/snailwalker/rails_projects/sample_app/app/views"
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.8486 seconds
44 examples, 4 failures
```

App/Controllers/sessions_controller.rb

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

      def new
      end

      def create
        user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
        if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
        else
          flash.now[:error] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
          render 'new'
        end
      end

      def destroy
      end
    end
```

spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "AuthenticationPages" do
    subject { page }
    describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }
it { should have_content('Sign in') }
it { should have_title('Sign in') }
end
describe "signin" do
    before { visit signin_path }
    describe "with invalid information" do
        before { click_button "Sign in"}

        it { should have_title('Sign in') }
        it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

        describe "after visiting another page" do
            before { click_link "Home" }
            it { should_not have_selector('div.alert.alter-error') }
        end
    end
    describe "with valid information" do
        let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
        before do
            fill_in "Email", with: user.email.upcase
            fill_in "Password", with: user.password
            click_button "Sign in"
        end
        it { should have_title(user.name) }
        it { should have_link('Profile', href: user_path(user)) }
        it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
        it { should_not have_link('Sign in', href: signin_path) }
    end
end
end
```

app/views/sessions/new.html.erb

```
<% provide(:title, "Sign in") %>
<h1>Sign in</h1>
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(:session, url: sessions_path) do |f| %>
        <%= f.label :email %>
        <%= f.text_field :email %>

        <%= f.label :password %>
        <%= f.password_field :password %>
        <%= f.submit "Sign in", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
        <p>New user? <%= link_to "Sign up now!", signup_path %></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do something between `if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])` and `else`.

A redirect I guess?

Comment: Yes you're right , but hartl only did put a mark there " # Sign the user in and redirect to the user's show page." Should i just skip this part and keep going on next?

Comment: yes he says redirect, so try to add `redirect_to user`

Comment: Thank u very much, he said he will replace  that signing comment with ruby code in the next chapter, i was confused , because before i move to next chapter, he clearly stated that"Now the test suite for users with invalid information should be green"

Comment: After replace that comment with 'redirect_to user' got another error '  1) AuthenticationPages signin with valid information 
     Failure/Error: it { should have_link('Sign out', href: signout_path) }
       expected #has_link?("Sign out", {:href=>"/signout"}) to return true, got false
     # ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:32:in `block (4 levels) in <top (required)>'

Comment: I think I will move on next chapter, we will see how it goes, but i will vote for this one, i didn't  actually read that comment until you mentioned it here!